# rJava classpath in an R package... works on some systems... not others

Tags: r, classpath, rjava

I have built a package for R that wraps R around some Java classes. On my development laptop (Ubuntu) this package loads properly and works great. On two other machines (one Ubuntu, one Debian) I have tried to use this package and the classpath is not being set by the `.jpackage()` call.

All three machines are running R 2.12.1 and rJava .8-8 which I believe to be the most recent.

The entire package is [up at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gsrad-r/source/browse/) but here's the contents of the zzz.R file which works to set the class path on one machine but not others:

```
##' @import rJava
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg) {
    pathToSdk <- paste(system.file(package = "GSRadR") , "/gsrad_sample/lib/", sep="")

    jarPaths <- c(paste(pathToSdk, "clima_core-1.0.0.jar", sep=""),
                  paste(pathToSdk, "clima_GSRAD-1.0.0.jar", sep=""),
                  paste(pathToSdk, "colt-1.0.jar", sep=""),
                  paste(pathToSdk, "commons-lang-2.0.jar", sep=""),
                  paste(pathToSdk, "junit-3.8.1.jar", sep=""),
                  paste(pathToSdk, "log4j-1.2.8.jar", sep=""),
                  paste(pathToSdk, "xqore.jar", sep="")
                  )    
    .jpackage(pkg, morePaths=jarPaths)
    attach( javaImport( c("java.lang", "java.io")))
    packageStartupMessage( paste( "GSRadR loaded. The classpath is: ", paste(.jclassPath(), collapse=" " ) ) )        
}
```

On my laptop this returns the following:

```
> require(GSRadR)
Loading required package: GSRadR
Loading required package: rJava
GSRadR loaded. The classpath is:  /home/jal/R/library/rJava/java /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/clima_core-1.0.0.jar /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/clima_GSRAD-1.0.0.jar /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/colt-1.0.jar /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/commons-lang-2.0.jar /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar /home/jal/R/library/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/xqore.jar
```

But on my other machines it returns only:

```
> require(GSRadR)
Loading required package: GSRadR
Loading required package: rJava
GSRadR loaded. The classpath is:  /usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/java
```

Any tips on what might cause the .jpackage() call to work differently on different machines? I've built packages using rJava before and used the same template for the `.onLoad()` function with no problems.

***Edit***

So on one of the machines where this was not working, I tried to simply add a path to the class path the "non package" way. And that failed:

```
> .jaddClassPath("/home/jal/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/clima_core-1.0.0.jar")
> .jclassPath()
[1] "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/java"
```

Um... so I can't add anything to the class path. But why?

***Edit II***

When I was loading my custom library onto one of the machines that was not working, I was using a temporary library location, like so:

```
install.packages("/tmp/GSRadR_0.01.tar.gz", lib=/my/path)
```

then loading the library like this:

```
require(GARadR, lib=/my/path)
```

I discovered, through trial and error, that if I remove the `lib=` bit it would work properly. So why would loading an R package that uses rJava into a custom library location keep the `.jaddClassPath()` function from working?

I may be able to work around this, but I'd love to know what's causing this odd (at least to me) behavior.

Comment: rJava has a help list IIRC. You may your luck try over there.

Comment: Question 1: You aren't quoting the `lib=` values.  Is that an error in the code or an effect of pasting into StackOverflow?

Comment: Question 2: Does the account that is doing the install/require have write permissions to the specified `lib` directory?  I've had that bite me in the rear when running code on multiple machines or with multiple users.

Comment: One other suggestion, as Elmer Fudd might say (so it sticks in the mind): be vewwy, vewwy careful about using `R CMD javareconf`.  When fortune favors you, it will fix all kinds of R and Java problems.  When fortune really hates you, someone will come and take away your privileges on that machine.  If at all possible, sucker someone else into running that command.  Ideally, the person who installed Java on that machine.  Fortune favors the prepared.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the directory or file in the first edit doesn't exist: `/home/jal/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/clima_core-1.0.0.jar`.  (Also, are you sure that you want to add that particular file, or the directory?)

Try `file.info("/home/jal/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/GSRadR/gsrad_sample/lib/clima_core-1.0.0.jar")`.

In my case, I tried `.jaddClassPath("/willy/wonka")` and it didn't work.  But when I tried `.jaddClassPath("/home/voldemort")`, it worked.  (Let Java be your horcrux.)

Comment: it's been a few months since I had this problem. I'll try to dig up the code and see how I actually solved it. Thanks for your comments and answer!

Comment: Yep, some time has passed.  :)  I was traipsing through unanswered questions.  Most unanswered questions on SO are pretty dull, but not this one.  If I can eliminate dull questions, that would be great.  ;-)

Comment: Ha! funny. Well I'm  glad that I didn't ask a dull question!